# Call to a member function isAdmin() on null in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, fatal-error

I want to basic authenticate **if User is Admin then Request next** otherwise redirect to homepage

**User.php**:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password','role_id','is_active','photo_id',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function role(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Role');
    }

    public function photo(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Photo');
    }

    public function isAdmin(){
        if ($this->role()->name=="administrator"){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

last function is `isAdmin()`

**Admin.php** (this is middleware):

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class Admin
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::check()){

            if (Auth::user()->isAdmin()){

                return $next($request);

            }
        }

        return redirect('/');
    }
}
```

**routes.php**:

```
<?php

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});


Route::get('/admin',function(){
    return view('admin.index');
});
Route::group(['middleware'=>'admin'],function(){

    Route::resource('/admin/users','AdminUsersController');

});




Route::auth();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
```

I get the following error:

> FatalErrorException in Admin.php line 21:
> Call to a member function isAdmin() on null

I also added `'admin' =>\App\Http\Middleware\Admin::class,` in kernel.php and imported the class in Admin.php.

Comment: @HilmiErdemKEREN what should i do

Comment: @HilmiErdemKEREN `null`  , why its null.iam logged in,then also `null`

Comment: @HilmiErdemKEREN would u plz help me :)

Answer (score 2):

This is because of no user session. Middleware works only when user is login. So you need to login first and then check for middleware

Answer (score 1):

`Auth::user()` return null if user is not authenticated.
to solve this issue  use Illuminate/Support/Optional as follows

```
optional(Auth::user())->isAdmin()
```

if `Auth::user()` return null then the `isAdmin()` will never be called.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this: change your method to ***static*** on User.php model.

```
    static function isAdmin(){
      if ($this->role()->name=="administrator"){
            return true;
       }
       return false;
    }
```

Next: Modify middleware it should work.

```
  <?php

    namespace App\Http\Middleware;

    use Closure;

    class Admin
    {
        /**
         * Handle an incoming request.
         *
         * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
         * @param  \Closure  $next
         * @return mixed
         */
        public function handle($request, Closure $next)
        {
            if (auth()->check()){

                if (\Admin::isAdmin()){

                    return $next($request);

                }
            }

            return abort(404); //redirect the user to not found page.
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you do not have any role, first insert some data in the `roles` table.